# How do I get Grails to map my String field to a Clob?

Tags: grails, groovy, orm, db2, grails-orm

My domain class looks like this:

```
package com.initech.tps

class Foo
{
    String stuff

    static mapping = {
        // mapping to a legacy table as opposed to letting Grails create it
        table name: 'FOO', schema: 'TPS'
        id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'MY_SEQ'], 
            column: 'FOO_ID', sqlType: 'integer' 
        foo column: 'STUFF'
    }

    static constraints = {
        stuff(nullable: true, maxSize: 40000)
    }
}
```

I was under the impression Grails would figure out to use a CLOB instead of a VARCHAR based on my passing in a big enough value for the maxSize constraint, instead I get this error message in the console:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in FOO for column STUFF. 
Found: clob, expected: varchar(40000)
```

Do I need an explicit sqlType on the mapping? I tried using different values of maxSize, and leaving it out altogether, with no difference. Also adding `sqlType: clob` or `sqlType: text` doesn't work.

I'm on Grails 1.3.7, using IBM DB2-Express.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer. Nothing like [reading the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/type.html) to find something out.

The change that worked was changing the mapping for the clob column to

```
foo column: 'STUFF', type: "text"
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's too late, but for future  references:

you just has to add a mapping

```
    static mapping = {  stuff type:'text' }
```

And that's all, grails change the data type to clob or any other that can hold large strings based in the database you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I used " Clob data" in my Grails project and that worked fine.

Can you use Clob ?

```
class Foo
{
 Clob stuff
 }
```

Comment: That would be one way to do it, I guess. I'd really like to see an answer that allows me to use a string in the domain object. There must be a UserType for this.

Answer (score 0):

Although actual Oracle DB column type is CLOB, `type:'text'` didn't help when `dbCreate` is set to `validate` in DataSource.groovy.

But this works for my Grails 2.2.0:

```
static mapping = { stuff sqlType: 'clob' }
```