# How can I store a Huge String in my Domain Class?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm making a web application in Grails, and I have this domain Class

```
String name
String query

static mapping = {        
    query type: "text"}
```

but when I bring the query from another query in Oracle, It returns a really huge String and I get this Error:

ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

From the database that i get the information, the fiels is varchar(63760)

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your mapping: `sqlType: 'clob'`. So you would have the following:

```
String name
String query

static mapping = {        
    query type: "text", sqlType: "clob"
}
```

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353353/using-oracle-10g-clob-with-grails-2-0-1) SO question.

Comment: I tried it, and type:'materialized_clob', and query(nullable: true, maxSize: 64000), and I read the other question, but I'm still getting stucked

Comment: I tried it again but I still having this error: ORA-12899

Answer (score 0):

Grails allows to set maximum size which gets converted to mySQL size, so you can try this if it works in Oracle.

```
class Class {
String name;
String query;

static constraints = {
    query(maxSize: 2048000)
}

static mapping = {
    query type: "text"
}}
```

Comment: I tried it but I still having this error: ORA-12899