# Grails 3 - Find object by CLOB value

Tags: oracle, grails, clob

Running *grails 3.2.10* against *Oracle 12g*.  I have a domain with a field that's a *CLOB*, I'm trying to find all instances of this domain that have a specific value in that field.

```
class SomeDomain {
  String name
  String value

  static mapping = {
    value sqlType: 'CLOB'
  }
}
```

I realize that *Oracle* doesn't allow direct equality comparisons of *CLOB* values...  *e.g.*,

```
SELECT * FROM some_domain where value = 'myValue'
```

will fail, but

```
SELECT * FROM some_domain where dbms_lob.compare(value, 'myValue') = 0
```

gives the correct results.

However, when I attempt to do HQL or Criteria queries to retrieve this in grails, it is attempting a direct equality comparison, and throwing Exception.

```
SomeDomain.findAllByValue('myValue') --> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

**It seems like I've already instructed grails to treat this column as a CLOB, is there a way to convince it to use `dbms_lob` comparisons for a specific query?**

I'm open to any other suggestions as well...  fairly surprised I couldn't find this question asked anywhere, maybe I'm just bad at searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to Grails, so I'm kind of guessing here. But I have a couple ideas to try.

Instead of `value sqlType: 'clob'`, I've seen [some people suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353353/using-oracle-10g-clob-with-grails-2-0-1) that you should use `value type: 'text'`, or `value type: 'materialized_clob'`. But I'm not sure what these actually do differently.

Or, instead of using a findAllBy*, I think you could use [Hibernate SQL Restrictions](http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/#_using_sql_restrictions) to do your query in native sql.

```
def c = SomeDomain.createCriteria()

def clobEquals = c.list {
  sqlRestriction "dbms_lob.compare(value, ?) = 0", ['myValue']
}
```

(I haven't actually tried this.)

Finally, as a workaround, you *can* use LIKE with clobs, and without include a wildcard it's equivalent to =

```
SomeDomain.findAllByValueLike('myValue')
```

This might not work with large string variables though.

Comment: Fantastic idea on the `sqlRestriction` (that I was unaware of), unfortunately, I wasn't clear that I needed hibernate to be aware of this as the application has multiple deployments against different databases, but I believe this would have worked based on the documentation.  The "like" comparison should be sufficient (I will do further testing to confirm, but I'm confident in your solution).